# Installing and using Gulp in a PHP environment?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Whats the best practice for installing and using node tools like Gulp in a PHP framework (specifically Symfony)?

For example I thought I would like to put my node_modules folder in my vendor directory like so:

./lib/vendor/node_modules

so I did:

```
npm install gulp -g --prefix=./lib/vendor/node_modules
```

But now when I try to run ./lib/vendor/node_modules/bin/gulp I get the error:

```
No local gulp install found
```

I'd rather not pollute the top level directory with things like an npm_module folder a gulpfile.js etc. I really consider all of that to be utilities which help my app function. Ultimately my goal is to integrate the gulp-sass preprocessing functionality into my app development workflow. How can I get gulp to work with this custom path?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error (in a different context). I needed to add --save-dev to the install command:

```
sudo npm install --save-dev gulp
```